# To redirect a file request from application server to apache server

Tags: apache

Currently my site's static content is residing in the application server. The plan is to move it to the apache server. But the problem I am facing is, as the html files are dynamic includes, the contentroot is getting attached to the request. And therefore, even though i am giving an 'Alias' in the virtual host of the apache conf, it does not get redirected properly.

For example:
My Jsp is footer.jsp inside which i am calling /static/footer.html as jsp include. The static folder is now under apache. 
So my url is:
  - //localhost:8840/ar/common/footer.jsp 
and i am trying to access:
  - //localhost:8840/static/footer.html. 
But the request is always processed as:
  - //localhost:8840/ar/static/footer.html.

In the 'virtual_hosts.conf' i have added: (running different hosts under the same IP)
  - Alias /static /opt/Apache2.0.54/htdocs/ar/static

I am completely new to Apache and would greatly appreciate any guidance. Hope the problem is clear. I could provide more details if any questions. I do not know what more details are needed. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Apache listening to port 8840? By default it is only set to 80.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use a symbolic link to link /static/ to /ar/static/.

`ln -s /static /opt/Apache2.0.54/htdocs/ar/static`

This will create a directory link named static in ar to the real static directory, so when you will try to access `localhost:8840/ar/static/footer.html` you will access `localhost:8840/static/footer.html`

Comment: could you please elaborate a little more? where should i specify the symbolic link?